# JS script doesn't work when I zoom in web browser

Tags: javascript, browser, jwplayer

Can anyone explain why this js script does not work when I zoom in my web browser?

```
function resizePlayer(){
 if(jwplayer().getWidth() == 596) { 
 jwplayer().resize(1004,565); 

 } else {
 jwplayer().resize(596,335);

 }
 };
```

Comment: Do you have a link that you can provide?

Comment: Provide more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function resizePlayer(){
 if(jwplayer().getWidth() == 596) { 
 jwplayer().resize(1004,565); 

 } else {
 jwplayer().resize(596,335);

 }
 };


you need attach the listener to an element such as window :

window.onresize = resizePlayer;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp